# How can I extract the part that is after @ in an email using php?

Tags: php, html

For example, if an email is Hello@domain.com
I want to get "domain.com"
I want to do that for several emails that are in a table using php.
and I want to calculate how many emails have a certain domain and display it as a percentage.
For instance : Domain1.com : 50%
               Domain2.com : 50%

```html
<html > 
    <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head> 
    <body> 
        
 <?php 
     $emails=array("email1@domain1.com","email2@domain2.fr","email3@domain3.com",
        "email4@domain4.com");
        $domain = explode('@', $emails)[4]; 
 ?>

    </body>
 </html>
```

I want to get :

domain1 : 25%
domain2 : 25%
domain3 : 25%
domain4 : 25%

Comment: `$domain = explode('@', $email)[1];`

Comment: @Mike is right, but this should be a place where you show us an example of your work so we can help you.  please provide your code

Comment: @Mike How can I use it with a table? I get the following error :Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: We really need to see some code, some test data e.g. the array of data that you are using, and what you expect to see. The  suggestion above should do what you want using the information as specified in your question. The error message you get suggests that the question is not as compete as it could be?

Comment: @RyanVincent I have updated the question

Comment: put the 'explode' in a `foreach ($emails as $email) { ...` loop?

Comment: I wrote : foreach( $emails as $emails)
  {
  $emails = explode('@', $emails);
  
  }
       echo $emails;

Comment: but I've got this error : Array to string conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want code like this

```
$emails=array("email1@domain1.com","email2@domain2.fr","email3@domain3.com", "email4@domain4.com",  "email233@domain4.com");
$results = array();

foreach($emails as $email){
    $domain = substr($email, strpos($email, "@") + 1);
    $result[$domain]  = isset($result[$domain]) ? $result[$domain] + 1 : 1;
}

foreach($result as $key=>$val){
    echo $key.": " . 100/array_sum($result)*$val . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! please if I want to round the result to show only 2 numbers after the comma, should I use  the function round()? I don't know how to use it, it keeps giving me errors

Comment: use number_format($number); read here http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php, If you liked my answer please mark it as a right answer.